# Change item in listview with dynamic objs and custom container

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

I've taken over some code from some previous programmers who have done some interesting things with a wpf listview.

The listview is build up from dynamic objects which determines each items text content. Which means that list.Items returns dynamic objects. The listview also have had its method "GetItemContainer" overridden which makes the containers of the items become instances of a custom class that inherites from listviewitem.

What I want to do is to put a highlight color om some items when another related item has focus. How do I accomplish this?

This far I've tried using triggers on the listview items to change color on selected and then select the items we need highlighted. That worked well at first, but we need the selection for something else.
I've also tried putting custom properties on the custom listviewitem. But that didn't work since the container repeats. 
I've also tried changing color on the content of the item instead of the item itself but that looked really weird.

I'm not great at wpf and I've tried Reading up about it but have been unable to find anything usefull about this particular case. Tips on search words/Reading material would also be much appreciated

Comment: Kindly add the code which you've tried so far

Comment: So in the end you will have a selected item, a focused item and some highlighted items in the same listview? Sounds like recipe for a messed up interface, but if you think its a good idea, you have to give more information about your current state of work.

Comment: If you use `DataTemplates`, `Binding` and `MvvM`. All this code that you are talking about is `[Obsolete("This code is no use since XAML can do it", true)]`. And what you are looking for is `<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>`.